# Converting DateTime to UTC and back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Maybe it will sound a bit weird, but i actually know a solution for this problem. My initial solution didn't work and i actually want to why. It is an Asp.Net MVC application.

This didn't work:

```
        public static DateTime ConvertToUTC(String userTimeZone, DateTime date)
    {
        var result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(userTimeZone));

        return result;
    }

    public static DateTime ConvertToUserTime(string userTimeZone, DateTime date)
    {
        var result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(userTimeZone));

        return result;
    }
```

I couldn't convert the time back to it's original time.

This did work:

```
public DateTime ConvertToUTC(String userTimeZone, DateTime date)
    {

        var result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(result, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(userTimeZone));

        return result;
    }

    public DateTime ConvertToUserTime(string userTimeZone, DateTime date)
    {
        var userTimezoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(userTimeZone);
        var result = date.Add(userTimezoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset);

        return result;
    }
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: It's very hard to know what's going wrong without any idea of the time zone involved, the input, the expected output or the actual output when it failed. I would suggest using my Noda Time project instead, mind you :)

Answer (score 0):

For this problem a special DataType is introduced in .NET 3.5: [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) it is functionally similar to [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) but it stores also a UTC offset.